# Google Adwords API Report Utilities - PHP - Invalid XML?

Tags: php, xml, report, google-ads-api

I got the AdWords API using PHP working and I am testing some of the functions. One function is generating a report via AWQL. So, everything works, but when I try to parse the Xml and try to convert it json, then some wierd error occurs. I am using the following code:

```
DownloadCriteriaReportWithAwqlExample($user, $filePath, $reportFormat);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($filePath);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

I get this error regarding the following line of code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($filePath);
```

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start 
>       tag expected, '<' not found in C:\PHP\Optima\adwords-examples-and-lib-
>       8.1.0\examples\AdWords\v201601\Reporting
>       \DownloadCriteriaReportWithAwql.php on line 91

The Xml looks correctly formatted. Has anyone ever had this error and knows what the issue is? Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 3):

Your gonna kick yourself...

`simplexml_load_string()` expects a *string* not a path to a file.  Either first read the file into a string or use `simplexml_load_file()`.

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file($filePath);
 $json = json_encode($xml);
```

Comment: Yikes. Embarrassing. Thanks!